# Install freetype on OSX Server 10.5.8

Tags: php, mac-osx-server

I'm running a webserver on my Mac Mini (OSX Server 10.5.8) which has GD installed but not with freetype support. Is it possible to install freetype on this machine? I searched the net but couldn't find a clear answer, could someone provide me with some hints or instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get yourself some [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Answer (score 2):

[Macports](http://www.macports.org/) has some freetype packages available.